# pip install from specific setup.py

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I created a python 3.3 app on RedHat's Openshift cloud service. By default it has setup.py for my project. I'm learning Udemy course called "Build a SaaS app with Flask" ([source code](https://github.com/nickjj/build-a-saas-app-with-flask))  Now I wanted to use python-click, as recommended by the course. It needs another setup.py for cli project; so to put that file in the project root folder, I renamed it to **setup_cli.py**. Now there are two files: **setup.py** and **setup_cli.py**.
Pip install seems to automatically look into setup.py.

```
# See Dockerfile in github source
pip install --editable <from setup_cli.py>
```

Can `pip install --editable` be used to point to setup_cli.py?

Comment: why don't you simply use `python <whatever-setup.py> develop`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that you can't do anything about it :-) - It's hard coded in pip source code :-)

If you try to use `pip install -e .`, it will call a method named [parse_editable](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/pip/req/req_install.py#L1115) which will run [this line](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/6ec55979300c836e35c2ac1b99bc1c78d96baef2/pip/req/req_install.py#L1010):

```
if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(url_no_extras, 'setup.py')):
    raise InstallationError(
        "Directory %r is not installable. File 'setup.py' not found." %
        url_no_extras
    )
```

You may want to to use this command `pip install -e file:///full/path/to/setup_cli.py`, but this command also appends a hard coded `setup.py` to your path :-)

In [setup_py](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/pip/req/req_install.py#L372) there is [this](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/pip/req/req_install.py#L387) line:

```
setup_py = os.path.join(self.setup_py_dir, 'setup.py')
```

so as @cel commented, it seems that `python <whatever-setup.py> develop` is your only option.